# Sumar un tipo de dato generico que puede ser (int, float o double)

Tags: java, genericos

mi problema es que tengo una clase generico `class MiClase <T>`, con T que puede ser `int`, `float` o `double`, y necesito crear un método que reciba un `ArrayList` y retorne un tipo T, que sea la suma de todos los elementos de la lista.
Saludos

Comment: Que has intentado?

Comment: Intenté hacer
<T> T sumar(T a, T b){
       if(a instanceof Integer){
             int i = a.intValue():
             int j = b.intValue():
             return (T)(i+j):
        }
}

Answer (score 0):

Bien campeon, dejame te explico, los tipos de datos primitivos no pueden ser genericos. Dicho esto puedes utilizar *wrappers* que son clases que contienen estos datos primitivos para tratarlos, por ejemplo en vez de `long` utiliza `Long`, en vez de `int`  utiliza `Integer`.

Ahora bien, yo recomendaria que antes de hacer un metodo generico hicieses uso de la sobre carga, es decir tener el mismo metodo para sumar diferentes tipos de valores , es decir:

```
sumar(List<Long> lista)
sumar(List<Integer> lista)
```

Ahora bien si  quieres realizar tu propuesta te recomiendo mejor hacer generico el ingreso de datos por metodo y no a nivel clase, es decir:

```
public <T> T sumar(List<T> list)
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, me fué muy útil esto de verdad. Gracias

Comment: Y lo de poner el tipo generico a la clase, era porque tengo más métodos que necesitan hacer también operaciones con cualquier tipo de dato númerico